# How to install Angular Datetimepicker without bower and npm?

Tags: angularjs, datetimepicker

I want to use [Angular Datetimepicker](https://github.com/zhaber/angular-js-bootstrap-datetimepicker) without bower and npm.

I include datetimepicker.js into my index.html

```
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/zhaber/datetimepicker/master/datetimepicker.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" >
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/zhaber/datetimepicker/master/datetimepicker.js"></script>
```

My app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [
    'ui.router',
    .....
    'datetimepicker',  // I try ui.bootstrap.datetimepicker and other names
]);
```

Also I have view and controller but now they are empty.

I get error:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

How to inject this library?

---

Addition 1:

[image]

And get error:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Comment: provide a fiddle to reproduce your error

Comment: I don't understand how to use it if I need create few files (html, js).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/2jyyaQuiRmlfS18qZjz1?p=preview) linked in the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/zhaber/angular-js-bootstrap-datetimepicker) I think you need to add both

```
angular.module('myApp', [...'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.bootstrap.datetimepicker']);
```

Comment: It's true for standard installation but for me not work. Add screen to question (addition 1)

Comment: it's a fiddle, it can't be installed through npm there. Are you adding the scripts in the page? In which order ? Show your completed index.html

Comment: Thanks I don't add ui-bootstrap-tpls in index file. On plunk I see only result page and can't return into code.